# Laravel 4/SimpleXML/PHP node no longer exists

Tags: php, xml, laravel, simplexml, laravel-4

I currently have a problem, my laravel site is returning an error. I'm using the following code:

```
    @extends('base')
@section('title', 'Experience stages')
@stop
@section('main')

<div class="container">
  <div class="doc-content-box">

    <legend>Experience stages</legend>


    <?php   

    $stagesdir = 'C:\Users\E1\Desktop\theforgottenserver-v0.2.15-win64console\Mystic Spirit\data\XML';   

    if(is_dir($stagesdir)) {   
      $list = simplexml_load_file($stagesdir.'\stages.xml'); 

      ?> 
      <table class="table table-striped">

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>From Level</th>
                <th>To Level</th>
                <th>Experience multiplier</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

      <tbody>
        <?php  
        foreach($list->children() as $stage) {  
            if ($stage['maxlevel'] == '') { 
        $stage['maxlevel'] = '*';     
        } 
            echo '  
            <tr>  
            <td>'.$stage['minlevel'].'</td>
            <td>'.$stage['maxlevel'].'</td>  
            <td style="width: 30%">'.$stage['multiplier'].'x</td>    
            </tr>';
        }  
      }
      else{
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger"><span class="label label-important">Error parsing your Monsters XML file</span><br /><br /> Invalid path!</div> ';
      }  
      ?>  
    </tbody>

  </table> 

</div>
</div>

@stop
```

In that foreach, I wan't to use `$list->world->children()` but it doesn't work for me. When I try to run my page, I get the following error:

```
main(): Node no longer exists
```

Also, here's my XML file: http://paste.laravel.com/Koh

I could use it without the `->world` but then, as you see in my XML file, it acts like an `<td>` in my table.

Comment: On what line (number or code) does the error occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I see your problem; your trying to get the attributes (maxlevel etc) from the first child-element, which is `<config>`, and that elements has only a 'enabled' attribute.
Try this;

```
<?php
$xml = '<stages>
<config enabled="0"/>
<stage minlevel="1" maxlevel="8" multiplier="7"/>
<stage minlevel="9" maxlevel="20" multiplier="6"/>
<stage minlevel="21" maxlevel="50" multiplier="5"/>
<stage minlevel="51" maxlevel="100" multiplier="4"/>
<stage minlevel="101" multiplier="5"/>
</stages>';
$list = simplexml_load_string($xml);

echo "<pre>";
foreach($list->children() as $child)
{
    switch($child->getName())
    {
        case 'config':
            echo 'Config->enabled: ';
            echo (string)$child['enabled'];
            echo "\n";
            break;
        case 'stage':
            echo 'Stage->minlevel: ';
            echo (string)$child['minlevel'];
            echo "\n";
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but it's needed to load it from the file. Could you do it from my script? I'm confused right now, can I do it in my script?

Comment: You can still use `$list = simplexml_load_file($stagesdir.'\stages.xml');`. I only used `simplexml_load_string` for my example that shows you how to use the $child (or $stage) variable in the foreach-loop.

Comment: yes, but it's now displaying the config enabled if it's 0 or 1. Could I disable it, to display nothing? :p

Comment: 1) You can leave the case for config empty, so it won't display anything, or 2) in your original foreach-loop, add `if($stage->getName() != 'stage')
 {
  continue;
 }` after opening the loop - this will skip the config node....